# Is there a way align text in both bottom right and left corners?

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer, text-alignment

I am trying to create align text so that it sits in both the *bottom right* and *bottom left* of the page, as a footer.

e.g.

JANUARY *(bottom left corner)* / 2019 *(bottom right corner)*

Can anybody help me with the HTML code for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please add some code of what you already tried and describe the problem of your question here.

Comment: Add some code so it can be reviewed :)

Answer (score 4):

Please check this JSfiddle: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/vuso16f9/4/)

I am using `flexbox` for alignment.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
</div>

<div class='wrapper'>
  <span>JANUARY</span>
  <span>2019</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Lukasz, however it still sits at the top of the page – I need it to be a footer.

Comment: To  make whole wrapper to be be at the bottom of the page i will need to know whole context and surrounding html elements. you can use. position:fixed; bottom:0 to the whole wrapper, with that it will be always at the boottom floating. you can use position: absolute etc. but a lot depends on html structure of your webpage.

Answer (score 0):

A version with `position: absolute` (for the older browsers).

```css
.footer {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: teal;
  position: relative;
}
.footer span {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
}
.footer span:first-child {
  left: 5px;
}
.footer span:last-child {
  right: 5px;
}
.footer span:last-child a {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #FFD500;
}
.footer span:last-child {
  right: 5px;
}
.footer span a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.footer span a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <span><a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">JANUARY</a></span>
  <span><a href="https://www.bing.com" target="_blank">2019</a></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! One other questions... Do you know the HTML code to hyperlink both words to separate pages so that there is no text decoration (no underline) but only change colour to blue when hovering mouse over each word?

Comment: Updated the solution above.

Comment: Only the left word works.....

<head>
<style type="text/css">
.footer{
position: fixed;     
text-align: left;
justify-content: space-between;
display: flex;
bottom: 10px; 
width: 100%;
font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;
Font-size: 30px;
letter-spacing:0em;
line-height:1.1em;
color:#0000FF;
padding:1em;
}
.footer span a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="footer">
    <span><a href="https://www.BLANKPAGE.com/NAME">NAME</span>
    <span><a href="https://www.BLANKPAGE.com/NEW-WORK">WORK</span>
  </div>
</body>
</a></a>

Answer (score 0):

Flex doesn't work on IE9 and some other browsers i'd use:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position:relative;
}

.wrapper span:first-child { 
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

.wrapper span:last-child { 
    bottom: 0;
    right:0;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <span>JANUARY</span>
  <span>2019</span>
</div>
```

Also if this was just to go in a websites header and footer, you could just add CSS to the 2 spans.

```css
.span_left { 
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

.span_right {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <span class="span_left">JANUARY</span>
  <span class="span_right">2019</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made an example using bootstrap (https://getbootstrap.com). If you are tring to implement a sticky footer, this is a simple and clean way to achieve your request.

https://jsfiddle.net/giacomorock/e6p7cbjz/2/

```css
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    line-height: 60px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      Test sticky footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="float-left">January</span>
    <span class="float-right">2019</span>
  </div>

</div>
```